# Alt+Space window menu to be circular

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, window

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.15.0-60-generic. I would like to be able to press <kbd>Up</kbd> and highlight *Close* when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in any window in Ubuntu desktop.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with the standard Alt+F4 keyboard shortcut?

Comment: my hands are not that big....

Comment: I just tried that (using Xubuntu 20.04) and what you describe works perfectly.

Comment: "my hands are not that big". Use your left hand to press the chord.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior cannot currently be changed by the end user, because this is how GNOME developers have decided that the Window menu (aka <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> menu) should work. There is a [feature request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/6017) for this option and a [merge request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/merge_requests/2525), so this might get implemented at some point.

---

Until the feature is implemented, I would suggest that you use a keyboard shortcut instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> → press <kbd>↑</kbd> → press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, as it can be much easier and faster to close a window this way (just one instead of three keyboard actions).

To add a shortcut you can do the following:

1. Open Settings.
2. Go to *Keyboard*.
3. Scroll all the way to the bottom and click *View and Customize Shortcuts*.
4. Click *Windows*.
5. Click *Close window*.
6. In the *Set Shortcut* window that pops up hit the shortcut of your choice, for example <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, and click *Set* (by default this shortcut is set to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, but <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> should be very close to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in terms of fingers stretching).

You will now be able to hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close the focused window. Personally, I have set this shortcut to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and it's very convenient.

Comment: @BasicOfCaerbannog Thank you very much. I will give them a try!

Comment: @Tom No problem! :D

Comment: Alt-Space <up-arrow> <Enter> works perfectly in Xfce (which relies on GTK3).